# Jenkins User cannot run selenium test: cannot open display, no protocol specified (Ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: java, linux, firefox, selenium, jenkins

I am currently trying to let Jenkins run a selenium-test I have written.
If I execute the jar-file with my user in command line, it works: Firefox opens and the actions I have defined in the script are taking place, but when I login as jenkins-user and execute the jar I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at com.example.tests.test_login_logout.setUp(test_login_logout.java:24)
    at com.example.tests.test_login_logout.testLoginLogout(test_login_logout.java:40)
    at com.example.tests.test.main(test.java:8)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox-bin) on port 7055; process output follows: 
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'CAPSIDT410', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-97-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at com.example.tests.test_login_logout.setUp(test_login_logout.java:24)
    at com.example.tests.test_login_logout.testLoginLogout(test_login_logout.java:40)   at com.example.tests.test.main(test.java:8)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    ... 9 more
```

I already tried to add Xvfb, changed the displayname, checked that I have the latest versions of Firefox and Selenium-server, downgraded my Firefox to previous versions, but nothing solved the problem.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that jenkins is not a regular user but a "service user" instead. I can only login with this user via command line, and only after I modified the user to require a password.

How can I make this test work with Jenkins?

Comment: If I had to guess your jenkins server doesn't run X.  =/  you might consider chrooting / or pbuilding your entire job so you can get the environment you need.

Comment: are you running it on a Grid or the machine where Jenkins is running?

Comment: How is your Jenkins running Xvfb?

Comment: Now i added tightvncserver as an vnc-server, before i only had xvfb installed and thought this is sufficient, which apparently it is not. In the jenkins job configuration, xvfb starts before the build and shutdown after, and xvnc will also be activated. Now i get another error message while building: the user environment variable is not set. for this purpose, i installed EnvInject too and added the USER = jenkins variable, but this doesnt solve the problem. Any ideas? @pArAs: Iam trying to run the tests on the same machine where jenkins is running

Comment: Hi, dekojo, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to clean up its formatting a bit, and also to make it better conform to this site's guidelines. We don't normally include greetings or things like "thanks in advance for any answers" in questions here, and questions are generally expected to contain at least one actual sentence ending with a question mark. See our [help center](/help/how-to-ask) for more information. If I've accidentally introduced any mistakes while editing your question, you're welcome to edit it yourself to fix them or even roll back my edits entirely.